# Elasticsearch 5.4.0 - How to add new field to existing document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In Production, we already had 2000+ documents. we need to add new field into existing document. is it possible to add new field ? How can i add new field to exisitng field

Comment: You can add new fields without any problem. Does the new field have the same value for all documents?

Comment: Do you mean that new documents will have an extra field or that old documents need to have a new, non-empty, field added to them? In the second case, what should be put in the new field for the existing documents?

Comment: @val.. just we need to add new field without value.. how can i add new field for all the document in single API call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-update-by-query.html) in order to add a new field to all your existing documents:

```
POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.new_field = 0",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Note: if your new field is a string, change `0` to `''` instead

Comment: You should be careful because the value you use will be used to determine the type of the field. Also, the ability to add fields on the fly is enabled by default, but may have been disabled in the configuration.

Comment: @Val If your new field is a string, change 0 to '' instead . what if new field in geo location?

Comment: @Nusrath feel free to a new question with your concrete example and reference it from here

Comment: @Val How to do it for nested fields?

Answer (score 0):

We can also add the new field using curl and directly running the following command in the terminal.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/you_index/_mapping/defined_mapping" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "properties":{"field_name" : {"type" : type_of_data}} }'
```